# Tapping a collection view cell to add annotations to a map

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, mapkit

Right now I have a map and a collection view that displays icons for the map. I want to make it so that when one of the icons is selected it displays those different locations within that specific category on the map; similar to Apple Maps.

```
 import UIKit
 import MapKit

 //Creating an outline for the different locations of places on the map
 struct PlacesOnMap {
 var name: String
 var latitude: Double
 var longitude: Double

init(name: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
self.name = name
self.latitude = latitude
self.longitude = longitude
}
}

 class ContentViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

 //Properties of collectionView, that determine number of items in the section and allows a single cell to be reused over and over again
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return imageArray.count
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
cell.mapIconImage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
cell.mapIconLabel.text! = imageNameArray[indexPath.row]
return cell
}

 //creating a constant for variables within the collection view such as the image and the title of the image
  let imageArray = [UIImage(named: "1"), UIImage(named: "2"), UIImage(named: "3")]
 let imageNameArray = ["image 1", "image 2", "image 3"]

 @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

 var places = [PlacesOnMap(name: "place 1", latitude: 28.551700, longitude: -81.374800),
 PlacesOnMap(name: "place 2", latitude: 28.553018, longitude: -81.374206),
 PlacesOnMap(name: "place 3", latitude: 28.553019, longitude: -81.367839)
]
 var buildings = [PlacesOnMap(name: "place 1", latitude: 28.556969, longitude: -81.364319),
 PlacesOnMap(name: "place 2", latitude: 28.558126, longitude: -81.364725)
]
 var recreation = [PlacesOnMap(name: "place 1", latitude: 28.54693, longitude: -81.393071),
 PlacesOnMap(name: "place 2", latitude: 28.538523, longitude: -81.385399),
 PlacesOnMap(name: "place 3", latitude: 28.542817, longitude: -81.378117),
 PlacesOnMap(name: "place 4", latitude: 28.538985, longitude: -81.404694)
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

mapView?.delegate = self
}

func setPlacesAnnotations() {
let places = places.map { placeOnMap -> MKPointAnnotation in
let place = MKPointAnnotation()
place.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placeOnMap.latitude, longitude: placeOnMap.longitude)
place.title = placeOnMap.name
return place
}
mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
mapView.addAnnotations(places)
}

func setBuildingsAnnotations() {
let places = buildings.map { placeOnMap -> MKPointAnnotation in
let place = MKPointAnnotation()
place.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placeOnMap.latitude, longitude: placeOnMap.longitude)
place.title = placeOnMap.name
return place
}
mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
mapView.addAnnotations(places)
}

func setRecreationAnnotations() {
let places = recreation.map { placeOnMap -> MKPointAnnotation in
let place = MKPointAnnotation()
place.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placeOnMap.latitude, longitude: placeOnMap.longitude)
 place.title = placeOnMap.name
 return place
 }
 mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
 mapView.addAnnotations(places)
 }

 //calls the functions up above when a cell from the collection view is selected
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
switch (indexPath.item) {
case 0: setBuildingsAnnotations()
case 1: setPlacesAnnotations()
case 2: setRecreationAnnotations()
default:
    break
}
}
}
```

Currently, the functions that places the annotations of the respected category are not being called. Is there a way to call these when an item from my collection view is tapped in order to achieve the desired results, or is there a better way to go about accomplishing this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 important missing steps in order to achieve what you asked with the code you provided:

1. Be notified when the user taps a cell of your CollectionView and inform MapViewController of the set of annotation to display
2. Provide a MKMapViewDelegate to your MKMapView

### Step 1

For the sake of brevity, I'm going to assume that your `ContentViewController` holds a reference to `MapViewController`, so that it can call the appropriate setAnnotations() function when a cell is tapped.

```
class ContentViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
  var mapViewController: MapViewController!
  let imageArray = ...
}
```

Next, we need to be informed when the user taps on one of those cells, for that we need to use a specific callback of [`UICollectionViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate) protocol:

```
class ContentViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
  ...
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch (indexPath.item) {
    case 0:
      mapViewController.setPlacesAnnotations()
    case 1:
      mapViewController.setBuildingsAnnotations()
    case 2:
      mapViewController.setRecreationAnnotations()
    }
  }
}
```

In this way, one of the three setXYZAnnotations function in MapViewController is called *each* time the user selects one of your cell.

We have a small issue to tackle before moving to the next step: MKMapView retains all the annotations added to it until those are removed. This means that each time you call one of the `setXYZAnnontation` function (hence, each time the user taps on a cell) a new set of annotation is appended to the map.
We have a simple way to discard all the annotations that were previously inserted into the map:

```
mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
```

This way, we're telling the map view to purge all the annotation it is currently holding. Make sure to add this line right *before* calling `mapView.addAnnotations(_)` in each one of your `setXYZAnnontation` functions.

### Step 2

When you add annotations or overlays on a map, it needs a way to be told *how* exactly you want those element to be rendered. This is accomplished by a [`MKMapViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate), just like a `UICollectionView` uses a `UICollectionViewDataSource` to know what `UICollectionViewCell` to use for a cell.

MapViewController is a good candidate to implement MKMapViewDelegate:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self
    ...
  }
}
```

Now, the protocol method you need to implement in MapViewController is [`mapView(_:viewFor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview), this function wants you to return an `MKAnnotationView` to associate with the specified annotation object you previously inserted.

There are mainly two approaches you can take:

- Simply return a `MKPinAnnotationView`: a bare, standard iOS-styled pin
  You can't customise the visual appearance of it other than its color

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
  let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView()
  pinView.pinTintColor = .green
  return pinView
}
```

- Return a `MKAnnotaionView` or subclass your own one, to fully customise the look of your annotation. In the following example I'm simply using a UIImage.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
  let iconView = MKAnnotationView()
  iconView.image = UIImage(named: "pin_icon")
  return iconView
}
```

Of course, in your app you'd want to differentiate the look of the annotation view depending on the specific set of annotations selected by the user.

*Note*: if you have a large number of annotations inserted in a map, these two approaches might lead to performance problems. In that case you need to [register](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/2887124-register) and [dequeue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452672-dequeuereusableannotationview) reusable annotation views, so that the map can recycle them. I suggest you to have a look at some [quick tutorial](https://blog.kulman.sk/using-custom-annotation-views-in-mkmapview/) and consult the [MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit) documentation to deepen the subject.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. The only problem is that my ContentViewController does not hold a reference to MapViewController. How would I add a reference?

Comment: That depends on how these two VCs are created in the first place. I suspect they might be part of the same "page" (do they appear on the same screen side by side?). If that is the case are they children of a container ViewController? Are they created entirely by Storyboard or by code?

Comment: Yes the appear on the same screen. They are created by storyboard. I've added a picture up above of the storyboard.

Comment: That's not an ideal setup: you are embedding two view controllers A, B as children of a parent view controller C, but in your case A (ContentVC) depends on B (MapVC). You can pass data to child VCs when they are embedded using the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method in the parent VC but you have no control on which one gets embedded first.
To solve this you can either:
- use NotificationCenter to decouple the two VCs
- collapse the two VC into a single one
- maintain the same structure by manually instantiate A and B, without using Storyboards

Comment: I have collapsed the two VC into a single one but when I click on a cell in the collectionView, nothing is displayed on the map.

Comment: I suggest you to use a few breakpoints to watch the code flow and debug where it stops.
You must verify the following func are called:
`collectionView(collectionView:didSelectItemAt:)` -> `setXXXXAnnotations()` -> `mapView(mapView:,viewFor:)`